# Bring Supersized Images To Show In Front of Page

Tags: wordpress, supersized

I am using the Supersized plugin in Wordpress with the tentyten theme and here's how it looks for my daughter's site.
http://www.theeplblog.com/beauty-1/
But I want only the images to show and not the page that's currently in front of it.
What do I need to do - so that my pages Beauty One and Beauty Two only show the slideshow images ?
I am using NextGEN Gallery for the images.
I'm not too skilled in css - but would really appreciate help.
Many thanks.